# Stratified sampling to fixed total size instead of stratified sizes

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse, slice

I have a dataset that I am looking to downsample as evenly as possible across a given variable. Lets say the dataframe is 54 observations and the fixed total size of the downsampled group is set at 25. However, because some of the n's in the stratification variable are small, it errors out when I try to select evenly across numbers since the number of observations in the smallest group is less than the expect stratification group size (in the example below, 2 < 5). Instead of duplicating observations using `replace = TRUE`, I would like a way to select all observations in the smaller groups and then pad the numbers from the other stratification groups until the specified sample size is met. Meaning, when the first group with only 2 observations cannot be sampled again, the numbers of the remaining groups would increase until I hit 25 selected. This would provide the most even downsampling by stratification group as possible without duplicates.

Below is my example with the error that I receive when I try to slice sample evenly. Because I am doing this using group_by, I am unable to specify the total sample size of 25. Is there a better method or a different function that is out there that I am unaware of that can easily sample this way? Or is there a way someone can help me discover that will allow for some sort of `group_by` + `slice_sample` combo to work

```
df <- data.frame(
  strat_group = c(rep("one", 2), rep("two", 10), rep("three", 5), rep("four", 25), rep("five", 12))
)

strat_group_size <- (25 / length(unique(df$strat_group)))

df |>
  dplyr::group_by(strat_group) |>
  dplyr::slice_sample(n = strat_group_size)

Error in `dplyr::slice_sample()`:
! Problem while computing indices.
ℹ The error occurred in group 3: strat_group = "one".
Caused by error in `sample.int()`:
! cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

What I would like is a method that would evenly downsample by stratification group until a specific number is reached (N = 25). The output would be something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  strat_group = c(rep("1", 2), rep("2", 6), rep("3", 5), rep("4", 6), rep("5", 6))
  )
```

I appreciate any help in advance! This problem has stumped me for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a tidyverse solution but you can do this via a loop in base R.

At each loop iteration you pick a row at random from the least represented group that still has elements left.

```
N=25            # how many rows do we want?
df$sampled = 0  # set each row initially to 'unselected'

for(i in 1:N){
  
  # find the number taken from each group, and the number remaining in each group
  
  df$totalpergroup=ave(df$sampled, df$strat_group, FUN=sum)
  df$remaining=ave((1-df$sampled), df$strat_group, FUN=sum)
  
  # choose an unselected row from the least represented group that has at least one row left
  # use this weird way of sampling a single value because of how 'sample' works when there's only one element
  
  possibleRows <- which((df$totalpergroup==min(df[df$remaining>0,"totalpergroup"])) & (df$sampled==0))
  rowToAdd <- possibleRows[sample(length(possibleRows),1)]
  
  # select that row
   
  df$sampled[rowToAdd] <- 1

}

# Here's my subsampled df

df[df$sampled==1,]

   strat_group sampled totalpergroup remaining
1          one       1             2         0
2          one       1             2         0
3          two       1             5         5
7          two       1             5         5
8          two       1             5         5
9          two       1             5         5
10         two       1             5         5
12         two       1             5         5
13       three       1             5         0
14       three       1             5         0
15       three       1             5         0
16       three       1             5         0
17       three       1             5         0
19        four       1             6        19
21        four       1             6        19
27        four       1             6        19
28        four       1             6        19
36        four       1             6        19
42        four       1             6        19
46        five       1             6         6
47        five       1             6         6
48        five       1             6         6
51        five       1             6         6
52        five       1             6         6
53        five       1             6         6
```